# The best tutorial to learn gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I am looking for gatling tutorial, but I could not find any interesting courses in google. I read documentation on offical website, but it is very short. Do you have any recomendation for gatling tutorials? Could be video. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I learned Gatling recently as well, using only resources found online and experimentation. Just google "gatling tutorial", there are plenty of links to pages showing gatling basics, many focus on different aspects so it's useful to read a number of them. The gatling documentation is pretty good as well, they also have an "advanced tutorial" covering more stuff. Gatling is open source, so you can always browse the source if you need more clarity on how something works.

Comment: Out of so many this is what I will suggest  :-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUPTaPms210